# Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Utils::chooseHandler() when sending email

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

My application was working fine and when I woke up today i faced this error:

> Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Utils::chooseHandler(

```
/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/php/plain/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php:42

function choose_handler(): callable
    
    {
    
        return Utils::chooseHandler();
    
    }
```

This is when the error happens:

```
Mail::to($request->email)->send(new ProfessionalInvited($clinic, $person, $inviteId));
```

What could happened? And what should I do? I already tried deleting my vendor and composer.lock and reinstall everything. But without success. I was also having this error in API calls using guzzle and when I changed to cURL everything worked fine. But I dont think I can do the same to send emails since Guzzle is a dependency.

Comment: Can you please share `composer.json`

Comment: Yes. This is my file https://pastebin.pl/view/0e733180

Comment: Can you please share the exception stack trace and the code where you're calling this

Comment: Here it is https://flareapp.io/share/o7Ag3NQm

Comment: Try this once, remove `guzzlehttp/guzzle` from `composer.json and run update. `aws/aws-sdk-php` already have `guzzle` as it's dependency so you don't need to add it again

Comment: Also, update the aws sdk version as well, this aws sdk is replacing the guzzle package

Comment: Removed guzzle and updated the aws sdk. Deleted the vendor and reinstalled the new dependencies. Still without success here.

Comment: As I can see from the stack trace, https://flareapp.io/share/o7Ag3NQm#F53 something is replacing the guzzle dependency... so I would suggest change this line `$stack = new self($handler ?: choose_handler());` to `$stack = new self($handler ?: Utils::chooseHandler());` in `vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php` it should work after that

Comment: Also, can you please share `composer.lock` file

Comment: I noticed that this function that shows in the stack trace as choose_handler() is actually writed in the vendor as Utils::chooseHandler(). So it is correct there! What could be happening?

Comment: I finally got it here. The composer was installing the most recent version of Guzzle but the aws sdk uses the version 6.5.5. I had to force it to install this specific version. Everything worked like a charm after that. Thanks for your help @Haridarshan

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what exactly happened but I can guess:

1. You installed wrong Guzzle version and it does not have `chooseHandler` method in `Utils` class (or it was reinstalled somehow on server).
2. Somehow file was removed
3. There was some problem with composer and you should run `composer dump-autoload`

I verified it and this method and class exists in Guzzle 7.x version and it's also mentioned in [documentation](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/handlers-and-middleware.html).

Comment: I tried composer dump-autoload but also without success. In my composer.json the version is 7.0.1. What more could I try?

Comment: @AntonyLeme See whether `vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php` file really exists and whether there is `chooseHandler` in this class. If not, you can try running `composer install`

Comment: Yes, the function is there

Comment: Inside the Utils I have chooseHandler and the guzzle is trying to call choose_handler. Does this make difference? This is how it is being called: 

$stack = new self($handler ?: choose_handler());

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem developing a WordPress plugin with a Guzzle dependency. The issue was another plugin using a different version of Guzzle.

See also "MAJOR_VERSION undefined class constant in src/utils.php": https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/2744